# Angular unit test image load with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In my angular project I have a directive that display a default icon before the real avatar was loaded.

```
function avatarDirective(API) {

    var DEFAULT_AVATAR = 'img/default-avatar.png';

    return {
      restrict    : 'A',
      scope       : {
        avatarUrl: '='
      },
      link: linkFunc
    };


    function linkFunc($scope, $element) {
      $element.attr('src', DEFAULT_AVATAR);

      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.avatarUrl;
      }, _setAvatar);


      function _setAvatar() {
        if ($scope.avatarUrl) {

          var avatar = new Image();
          avatar.onload = function() {
            $element.attr('src', API.BASE_URL + $scope.avatarUrl);
          }
          avatar.src = API.BASE_URL + $scope.avatarUrl;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

This code works correctly without problem.
But I'm unable to test it with Karma. Indeed the load function is never trigger. Here is my test below.

```
it('should set the default avatar if avatar-url is empty', function(done) {
    element = angular.element('<img class="img-circle" dod-avatar avatar-url="avatar"/>');
    element = $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.avatar = 'img/new-avatar.png';
    $scope.$digest();

    expect(element.attr('src')).toContain('img/new-avatar.png'); // FAILED

  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(element.attr('src')).toContain('img/new-avatar.png'); // FAILED
```

This will always fail. The attr() returns an attribute's value and toContain matcher from Jasmine is handling only arrays ([jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers)).